# javascript not being interpreted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

At one point my code compiles correctly - all the lines etc - but the same code at a different place (by place i mean function) does not compile completely.

Here is the code:

```
function updateEmployeeFunction() {

    updateFields.username = $("#usernameTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.password = $("#passTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.confPasswrord = $("#confPassTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.firstName = $("#firstNameTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.lastName = $("#lastNameTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.email = $("#emailTxtInfo").val();
    updateFields.phone = $("#phoneTxtInfo").val();

    validateUsernameUpdate(updateFields.username);
    validateEmailUpdate(updateFields.email);
    validateFirstNameUpdate(updateFields.firstName);
    ValidatePhoneUpdate(updateFields.phone);
    validatePasswordUpdate(updateFields.password);
    validateConfirmPasswordUpdate(updateFields.password, updateFields.confPasswrord);

    if (updateFields.usernameCheckSuccess == true && updateFields.emailCheckSuccess == true &&
            updateFields.firstNameCheckSuccess == true && updateFields.phoneCheckSuccess == true &&
            updateFields.passwordCheckSuccess == true && updateFields.confPassCheckSuccess == true) {

        callUpdateUser();
    }
}
```

and heres the code for the update user

```
function callUpdateUser() {
    $(".ajaxLoader").show();

    var URL = getUpdateUserUrl();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        cache: false,
        processData: true,
        success: updateUserCallSuccess,
        error: ajaxError
    });
}
```

The function `updateEmployeeFunction` is called when the update button is clicked,
and the validate functions, all of them, update the `updateFields.checks` respectively.

What my code is doing is that it is validating well and good but it does not go to the if part, where the real update is, but when i put debugger on it, it runs correctly.

Am I doing something wrong here and I have to click the update button twice to get it working?

And btw I am making a page in asp.net

Comment: I didn't know JavaScript could even *be* compiled. I thought it was an interpreted scripting language... What compiler are you using? And what error are you getting?

Comment: What is `updateFields`? Is it an object? I can't find any reference to it anywhere.

Comment: oh sorry, not compiling, hehe,  my bad, its interpreted...

Comment: Try checking the javascript console in your browser. (F12 in chrome > console) EDIT: I guess you've said it compiles correctly, so it must not be giving an error(?)

Comment: Do you see any (javascript)console output? Are you certain that those "success" values really *are* true (as opposed to *should be* true)? Check for typos (ValidatePhoneUpdate with a capital V? "confPasswrord"?

Comment: this is the problem, its not giving me any errors, its running fine, but i have to press the button twice to make it work

Comment: no i dont think there is any typo, because when i use breakpoint in firebug, and move step by step, it works perfect on the first click

Comment: The issue is not on the lines that you have place here. I do not place -1 because you have no reputation, but this is not a good question at all.

Comment: **i have to press the button twice to make it work** ?? Can you put your button click code ? I mean are you using asp:Button or any ?

Comment: sorry aristos, but i dont know which part of code to post, its really large to put all of it, and secondly, and ive debugged all the code, but cant find any mistake, this is really weird thing to happen....at the end i put "press twice" underneath the button....

Comment: ok wait.... `$(document).ready(function () { $("#updateBtnInfo").bind('click', updateEmployeeFunction); });`

Comment: this is it, i am just binding the button using jquery....

Comment: `ValidatePhoneUpdate` has an upper case "V". Is this your problem or is it just a typo?

Comment: no i've checked it, its neither typo nor a mistake, i've named the function with a capital V mistakenly, and i did'nt changed it....

Comment: are you using ajax for the validation? I'm thinking maybe the validation isn't complete by the time you reach the update if.

Comment: yea, that might be the case Elad, but the thing is, the same form is being used for creating a new user, which in turn uses the same kind of validation...and only username uses ajax validation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are you using ajax for the validation? I'm thinking maybe the validation isn't complete by the time you reach the update if. by Elad

This was exactly what was happening, thanx mate for your reply,

i delayed the if for 500 ms, and now, it works perfectly...